# AWS CloudWatch Agent Logs Stream - how to enforce new log_stream per log_group for every day

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, pm2

I have a `node` process being run via `pm2`. I have both the normal logs & error logs being written to the same file.

I am using `AWS CloudWatch agent` to send logs to `AWS CloudWatch`. But sadly there is no way I can enforce the agent to create new `log_stream` for every day to make log management better. Else it will keep writing it in the same `log_stream` & it will become bulky to handle.

How can I enforce the `AWS CloudWatch agent` to write to different `log_stream` in the same `log_group` for each day?

My config.json file:

```
{
  "agent": {
    "run_as_user": "cwagent"
  },
  "logs": {
    "logs_collected": {
      "files": {
        "collect_list": [
          {
            "file_path": "/home/user/listener-logs/out.log",
            "log_group_class": "STANDARD",
            "log_group_name": "sqsListener-logs-dev.log",
            "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}",
            "retention_in_days": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have also tried to replace `"log_stream_name": "{instance_id}",` with `"log_stream_name": "{date}",` but it doesn't work and just create one `log_stream` of the day we start it.

Comment: What exactly is it you're doing with your logs that splitting them into different streams per day makes easier?

Comment: Splitting them makes the management easy. So generally, while reporting issues with API client provides the date of incidence, hence going to that date's log will result into easy & quick bug resolution.

Comment: If you're just go to your log group in AWS console and click on "Search Group", it will give you the list of all events in the group from all the streams, which you can then limit by date using the date picker. I'm not sure CloudWatch Agent is able to rotate the logs without restarting it every day. Wish that I were wrong.